# Angular material sidenav with flex-layout - Not able to route to different pages

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Need help on how to route to different pages when I click on hyper links (when the browser is full window and not full window, that means the menu at the right top corner).

Created [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvazdp).

Do I must need mat-sidenav-content **fxFlexFill** and provide height mat-sidenav-container

```
.mat-sidenav-container{
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  min-height: 93vh !important;
}

<div> 
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

    <a mat-button class="companyName" routerLink="/">
      <span>Site name</span>
    </a>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">
      <a mat-button routerLink="/about">About us</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/prices">Prices</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/start-page">Start page</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/offer">Offer</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>

  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill class="example-container">

    <mat-sidenav color="primary" #sidenav fxLayout="column" mode="over"  opened="false" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <div fxLayout="column">
        <a mat-button routerLink="/about">About us..</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/prices">Prices</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/start-page">Start page</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/offer">Offer</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
      Awesome content
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an issue ? It seems to work and you don't ask any question ...

Comment: @trichetriche - Yes, I had the question and it was "how to route to different pages when I click on hyper links"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't actually a problem. The reason your not seeing the router work is because you are rendering an element on top of your router outlet

```
<div> 
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

    <a mat-button class="companyName" routerLink="/">
      <span>Site name</span>
    </a>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">
      <a mat-button routerLink="/about">About us</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/prices">Prices</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/start-page">Start page</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/offer">Offer</a>
      <a mat-button routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>

  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill class="example-container">

    <mat-sidenav color="primary" #sidenav fxLayout="column" mode="over"  opened="false" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <div fxLayout="column">
        <a mat-button routerLink="/about">About us..</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/prices">Prices</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/start-page">Start page</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/offer">Offer</a>
        <a mat-button routerLink="/contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
      Awesome content // <-- RIGHT HERE should be router outlet, this is what is displayed as the main 'content'
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

so change

```
<mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
   Awesome content
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

to

```
<mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clue that to keep the router-outlet inside mat-sidenav-content. Not sure why I am not getting this in any tutorial or examples. I see someone downvoted my question. Would you mind to upvote that. If I get couple of more -ve vote, I can't ask questions anymore in this forum. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SK Nice to hear you solved the problem. I'm not going to just give you up-votes, that wouldn't be constructive. What you can do is edit your post and improve on feedback people give you (look at the comment below your post **hint hint**). If you improve your post, the person that down-voted might revoke his vote.

Comment: (just to be clear, it wasn't me that downvoted your question, I usually downvote answers)